# Javascript: Special character in a javascript object property string.

Tags: javascript, string, object

I have a variable with some object/properties and I need to add a trademark to one of them. Is this possible?

```
var something = {
    name: "This is trademarked",
    //some more objects
};
```

I tried applying it this way:

```
var trademark = document.write("\u2122");
var something = {
    name: "This is trademarked" + trademark,
    //some more objects
};
```

But shows as undefined.

Comment: What encoding do you want this symbol in? The HTML version is `&trade;`

Comment: I've tried different encodings, all of them are undefined.

Comment: It will be in html format I suppose.

Comment: You suppose? This is going to be hard to answer unless you can give a straight answer to that question.

Comment: document.write has no return value. This is why you get undefined.

Comment: I have a bunch of rout parameters set up, and several js files linking to one another. In this instance the object simply displays the title to an html div within a another js file. So yes, it should be html format.

Comment: `document.write` isn't going to display anything in a div..

Comment: Liam, I originally had it as innerhtml I think but for whatever reason I saw a thread describing .write for encoded symbols.

Comment: [Note: as document.write writes to the document stream, calling document.write on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls document.open, **which will clear the document**.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write)

Comment: Please don't add your solution into the question. Accept the answer that helped if any did or add an answer to your own question. Questions should only contain questions.

Comment: His solution didn't actually work, so should I just add my own answer? It just got me to the solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var something = {
  name: "This is trademarked",
  //some more objects
};

var trademark = "\u2122";

something.name += trademark;

// this is just to show the result, don't used it in a real case
document.write(something.name)
```

Comment: Ok, OP is using `document.write` o_O this needs an explanation of what you've done and why.

Comment: yes, I used it because his example.. but can be omitted and use other function

Comment: Its a contrite example so I think document.write is OK to illustrate that it works

Comment: I'm pretty sure some of the OPs problems is that he's using `document.write` but this does kinda answer the question.

Comment: this did the trick actually with just adding the var something {name: "something" + trademark }

Answer (score 0):

Eduardo's solution got me to the solution that worked for me in case anyone else views this in the future.

```
var trademark = "\u2122";
var something { 
    name: "some text " + trademark,
    //more object
}
```